# Webview vs. Native Client

Tags: android, webview

I was trying to display a webpage of a url on a plain WebView, and some of the images are not showing. However, everything shows up fine in the browser for the simulator.

Is there a difference between the rendering via WebView vs. the Android 2.3 Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things added to the Android browser.  They add things in to handle JavaScript, to handle switching to native functionality for videos, etc.  Luckily the Browser is open source so you can get the Android code base and see what they do.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate.  android.webkit.WebView can also be configured to handle JavaScript

Comment: Right, but it's not by default.  Which is my I suggested looking into the Browser so he can see how they make the WebView handle it all.

Comment: fair point! There is a bunch of other stuff that you get with Browser tooo

Answer (score 0):

Yes could be a difference. If you are passing the web text-plain to the webview directly it doesn't understand the images which are references depending the local path instead the goblal path reference.

I mean, if you have a `<img src="/images/image.png" />` here you are referencing depending on your directory, and the browser try to look up image.png into your root, and if you have `<img src="http://www.whatever.com/images/image.png" />` then you are referencing it globaly. So I think this is the main that you could have.